# In Tensorflow, how can I write Tensors to disk using multiple threads?

Tags: tensorflow

In a standard image pipeline, I might use a QueueRunner which will handle keeping a queue of data full by using multiple threads to read data from disk. I want to do the inverse of this process i.e. to use multiple threads to keep a queue mostly empty, by dequeueing and writing these values to disk (I'm saving many images, so it's important this is non-blocking). What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: you purpose is to make sure your dequeueing and writing never be blocked, right?  I am confused by why you want your queue be empty.  if you want your dequeue action don't get blocked, one of the condition is that your queue can always feed your writing action whenever it want more image.

Comment: Not quite, the idea is to process the output of the pipeline, as opposed to the input of the pipeline. So the pipeline would generate a bunch of images and push them into a queue, and we want some other threads to be processing these images as they come in and writing them to disk.